# Removing (tax) lines from checkout review

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, tax

At moment my review at the checkout page looks like this:

```
Subtotal
Delivery Costs
Total without tax
Tax
Total with tax
```

I would like to hide the lines: **Total without tax** and **Tax**. I have tried editing the `item.html` and `tax.php` pages but have not been able to hide these lines.

How do I hide these lines? Im using Magento 1.9. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Saying, "I edited the code and it doesn't work" is not a helpful statement. Show relevant code that you edited. Be descriptive. Your question as-is is not appropriate for this format.

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. I have deleted the line: <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?> but the lines keep showing up, i can't find the right line to delete.

Comment: I have tried removing: <?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer', $_colspan); ?> from totals.phtml, but it lets Total without tax and Total with tax dissapear, i just want Total without tax to dissapear, any ideas?

Comment: Also i have found the file grandtotal.phtml but... how remove the tax line from checkout? Thanks
Ale

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the tax display in cart.

Follow this link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-sales-tax-shopping-cart-display-settings

And you can sort totals in cart:

You can configure it in the Magento backend itself. Go to System->Configuration->Sales->Checkout Total Sort Order.Set the sorting order as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i can modify the display, but not letting lines dissapear unfortunately.

Comment: You can also hide the taxes with css. Thus do not have to modify the phtml. But if you can't hide with css you can try this: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards%20/viewthread/28105/#t332953

Comment: One more question, i've removed the tax line with above link, thank you for that! I've got 2 more situations i just cant find out. I can't remove the line: Subtotal without tax, i just can't find the code to remove this line. Besides that i've got the line Shipping and Handling, i've translated this into: Verzendkosten. The line now says: Verzendkosten (Verzendkosten) while my translation file: Mage_Sales.csv only says Verzendkosten, translated from Shipping & Handling. Any idea where the other text between ( and ) comes from? The shipping.html pays only says Shipping & Handling once.

Comment: I have tried removing the code:

<tr>
                    <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                    <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                </tr>

from info.phtml, i've searched up the name with developers tool from my website, but it keeps showing up with the subtotal.

Comment: I have tried removing: <?php echo $this->renderTotals('footer', $_colspan); ?> from totals.phtml, but it lets Total without tax and Total with tax dissapear, i just want Total without tax to dissapear, any ideas?

Comment: Found it, it was in grandtotal.phtml.